# Deploying a modified chaincode

Tags: blockchain, hyperledger

I followed this guide

https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/blob/master/docs/dev-setup/devnet-setup.md

I deployed the chaincode as the command

CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=172.17.0.2:30303 ./peer chaincode deploy -p github.com/hyperledger/fabric/examples/chaincode/go/chaincode_example02 -c '{"Function":"init", "Args": ["a","100", "b", "200"]}'

It worked normally.

Then I modified the chaincode and re-deployed.

But I didn’t see this change impacting on validating peers.

Who could give me some ideas about this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you say modified the chaincode and redeployed, did you also build the peer image (by doing "go test -run BuildImage_Peer" in the container directory) and restart the peers ?

In fact before you do that, its good to check if the changes were good by testing in  "--peer-chaincodedev" mode. Once you did that, do remove the chaincode executable from the source directory (its transient and needed only for dev mode).

If it still does not work, we'd need logs.